# NON-EU spouse of EU citizen at the same time a british citizen

Tags: maltese-citizens

I am married an EU citizen at the same time british citizen we live now in malta. I have to plan to travel in UK this december 2014. Do i need a visa to travel in uk?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: This is not very clear. Who is the British citizen? You or your spouse? What is your nationality?